# Laravel get api from curl than jsondecode with ajax

Tags: jquery, laravel, lumen

I have an index route  http://localhost/index
I need help to create  jquery ajax to get  the json data from url http://localhost/mylist  and  format the json data to display it as a html table.

Here is my 2 routes in Laravel

```
 Route::get('index', function () {
 return view('index');
 });

 Route::get('mylists', 'ExampleController@mylists');
```

Here is ExampleController.php  method

```
public function mylists()
{

\\Here i do a cURL get request to my remote api befor I return $data

 return $data = json_decode($contact_list)

}
```

So if Someone navigate to  url  http://localhost/mylist they will see

```
{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}
```

I have an index route as well  http://localhost/index
I need help to create  jquery ajax to get  the json data from url http://localhost/mylist  and  format the json data to display it as a html table.

Comment: Please clarify you question, you mean don't know how to request ajax?

I saw a problem is in your route `Route::get('mylists', 'ExampleController@mylists');` but your define function `mylists()` in `myController.php `

Comment: Yeah sorry that was typo i define all methods in  ExampleController.php 

yeah i am trying to  get the json data from my method mylists using ajax and show it on my index page...

Comment: So you can use Jquery [Doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to request data from your server, and loop through those data to organize your UI. Because you can access [ http://localhost/mylist]( http://localhost/mylist) and return json already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the data to view from the controller

```
 public function mylists()
    {
     $data['mylist'] = json_decode($contact_list);
     return view('myview',$data);
    }
```

Create view file myview.blade.php to render the data in html format

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr>

<th> Name</th>
<th> Age</th>
<th> City</th>
</tr>
@foreach($mylist as $list)
<tr>
<td>{{ $list->name}}</td>
<td>{{ $list->age}}</td>
<td>{{ $list->city}}</td>                                        
</tr>
@endforeach 

</table>
```

Comment: thanks this is nice solution for normal case  but i have  to keep mylist method to only return Json and not pass to any view  and than on my index page i have to use ajax to  get the json that is returned from mylist method and than on the index page i have to than format the json data into html table.

Comment: Here is the solution by using jquery AJAX to display as a table format `$.ajax({
 context: this,
 url: YOUR_URL,
 type: 'GET',   
 dataType: 'JSON',
 success: function (data) { 
 var mylists = $.parseJSON(data);
  var mylisttable = '<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>City</th><tr>';
  $.each( mylists, function( index, value ){
     mylisttable = '<tr><td>value.name</td><td>value.age</td><td>value.city</td></tr>';
  });
  $('body').html(mylisttable);
 }
});`